# Failure message when using as.factor() method in RStudio

Tags: r

Failure message when using as.factor() method

I try to create two new data variables extracted from the following variable format e.g.:

```
> str(movies$Date)
 chr [1:100] "Apr 26, 2019" "Dec 17, 2021" "Apr 27, 2018" "Dec 18, 2015" "Dec 15, 2017" "Jun 12, 2015" ...
```

I tried it like this:
####Month treated as a factor; year numeric or categorical)

```
movies$month <- as.factor(month(movies$Date))

movies$year <- as.factor(year(movies$Date))
```

but get the following error:

```
`Error in as. POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  String is not in a unique standard format`
```

Comment: Please include some more details about your dataframe or `Date` column in your question, i.e. output of `str(movies$Date)` or `dput(head(movies))`

Comment: Are you using lubridate/tidyverse?, what if you use `month(parse_date_time(movies$Date, orders = "mdy", locale = "EN_us")`?

Comment: it gives me back the month as date_time variable... but i am supposed to return it as a factor...

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

You need to use (in this case) `lubridate::mdy()` to convert the character string to a date before extracting the month and converting it into a factor.

```r
datestr <- c("Apr 26, 2019", "Dec 17, 2021", "Apr 27, 2018", "Dec 18, 2015", "Dec 15, 2017", "Jun 12, 2015")
library(lubridate)
factor(month(mdy(datestr)))
## [1] 4  12 4  12 12 6 
## Levels: 4 6 12
```

@RicVillalba's suggestion of using `parse_date_time(movies$Date, orders = "mdy", locale = "EN_us")` in place of `mdy()` is probably more robust.